# Detect renderer window's monitor change using GMFBridge

Tags: c#, video, directshow, renderer, directshow.net

I want to render and record video from an analog camera using DirectShow. When I move renderer window from one monitor to another, graph gets restarted and restarting the graph causes recording lost. To aviod this, I started using GMFBridge. I encode and write video to a file and using Infinite Tee, I pass frames to second graph which renderer is there. So when renderer graph restarts, my recording graph won't affect.

But when I move window to another monitor, second graph (renderer graph) stops and all I see is black screen. Why renderer graph doesn't start after stop when using GMFBridge?

I think I should handle events. I figured out that when I move window to another monitor, I receive these messages:

```
#define EC_VMR_RENDERDEVICE_SET 0x53

#define EC_PAUSED               0x0E
```

But I don't know if handling these messages is right or not (to understand monitor change).

Answer (score 0):

I changed video renderer filter from [Video Renderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [Video Mixing Renderer Filter 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and now everything is working fine. When I move window to another monitor, graph restarts without problem. Since I use GMFBridge, restarting renderer graph doesn't affect my recording graph.